# After creating layer by means of PyQGIS it does not show up on the map

Tags: pyqgis, point, layers, qgsmapcanvas

I made a script in PyQGIS to create a layer but the layer does not show up on the map.

Can someone help me?

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "temporary_points", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
    
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("name", QVariant.String),
QgsField("age", QVariant.Int),
QgsField("size", QVariant.Double)])
vl.updateFields() # tell the vector layer to fetch changes from the provider

fet = QgsFeature()
fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(531269,6725438)))
fet.setAttributes(["Johny", 2, 0.3])
pr.addFeatures([fet])

# because change of extent in provider is not propagated to the layer
vl.updateExtents()

print("fields:", len(pr.fields()))
print("features:", pr.featureCount())
e = vl.extent()
print("extent:", e.xMinimum(), e.yMinimum(), e.xMaximum(), e.yMaximum())

features = vl.getFeatures()
for fet in features:
    print("F:", fet.id(), fet.attributes(), fet.geometry().asPoint())
```

Comment: Is your spatial reference defined and is the number valid within the scope of the spatial reference? It might be drawing but off the screen or over the horizon.

Comment: If I zoom in on the object it does not show up

Comment: I think you forgot `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)`

Comment: I added the line but I still can't see the point

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments from both @Michael Stimson and @Taras are correct. You need to pass a CRS to the vector layer constructor and add the layer to the project. In addition you also need to enable editing on the layer before adding your attribute fields and features. You can either do that via:

```py
with edit(vl):
    #add your attributes and features
    ...
```

Or with the `vl.startEditing()` and `vl.commitChanges()` commands.

Modifying your code snippet below, (I just used EPSG:3857 to test):

```py
vl = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=epsg:3857', 'Temp_points', 'memory')
pr = vl.dataProvider()

vl.startEditing()

pr.addAttributes([QgsField("name", QVariant.String),
                    QgsField("age", QVariant.Int),
                    QgsField("size", QVariant.Double)])
vl.updateFields()

fet = QgsFeature()
fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(531269,6725438)))
fet.setAttributes(["Johny", 2, 0.3])
pr.addFeatures([fet])

vl.commitChanges()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)

print("fields:", len(pr.fields()))
print("features:", pr.featureCount())
e = vl.extent()
print("extent:", e.xMinimum(), e.yMinimum(), e.xMaximum(), e.yMaximum())

features = vl.getFeatures()
for fet in features:
    print("F:", fet.id(), fet.attributes(), fet.geometry().asPoint())
```

I got the following result. Note- I don't know the point is in the correct location since I don't know which CRS your coordinates are actually in. That is up to you to determine and pass to the class constructor.

[image]

If you want to write your features to a vector file rather than creating a temporary layer, you can use the [`QgsVectorFileWriter`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#details) class. The script below shows you how to create a GeoPackage, but by changing the `driverName` argument you can save to other vector formats (shapefile etc.) You will need to change the `save_path` variable to your own desired file location.

```py
# Path below is an example; change this to point to where you want to save to
save_path = 'C:\\Users\\Your\\Save\\Directory\\filename.gpkg'

fld_lst = [QgsField("name", QVariant.String),
            QgsField("age", QVariant.Int),
            QgsField("size", QVariant.Double)]

fields = QgsFields()
for f in fld_lst:
    fields.append(f)

# Make sure you pass the correct CRS to the class constuctor
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(save_path,
                             'utf-8',
                             fields,
                             QgsWkbTypes.Point,
                             QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('epsg:3857'),
                             "GPKG")

fet = QgsFeature()
fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(531269,6725438)))
fet.setAttributes(["Johny", 2, 0.3])
writer.addFeatures([fet])

del writer

# You can pass a different layer name instead of 'test'
vl = iface.addVectorLayer(save_path, 'test', 'ogr')
```

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: @Sander, you're welcome. https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I have another question. Because right now the code creates a temporarily layer. Is there a way to save the layer with code?